# How to get correct line numbers in symbolicated crash reports (iPhone / Mac)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, crash-reports

When symbolicating crash reports, I noticed that line numbers are off. I tested this with a project in which I deliberately cause a crash. It seems the generated line number do not include certain lines, e.g. comment lines or compiler preprocessor statements (not sure what it does and does not include)...

Is there an easy way to get from the "off" line number in the symbolicated crash report to the actual line of code in the source?

Edit:
An example of a line in a symbolicated crash report:

```
7 Luisterpaal 0x00005de2 -[SWFMP3 connection:didReceiveData:] (SWFMP3.m:320)
```

So, the line number 320 is almost correct, but not exactly. It's a few lines off...

Comment: This [Technical Note](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html) shows how to relate the report to code

Comment: I wasn't able to get more accurate line numbers, but that's a killer resource to bookmark.

Answer (score 10):

In a word… no. If you're looking at a line like this in a crash report:

> 0  com.apple.CoreFoundation  0x95cb046b  CFArrayAppendValue + 43

The "+43" isn't a line number, but a memory location from the beginning of the function. The code as you wrote it simply doesn't exist in the compiled binary - the compiler optimises and changes the code (in a Release build, at least) around so it most often doesn't match what you wrote.

Unfortunately, the solution is to provide the person experiencing the crash with a debug version that you can remote debug or at least throw out NSLog() statements to help track it down, and/or write smaller methods.

Comment: I meant the numbers of a symbolicated crash log e.g. the "320" in:

7 Luisterpaal 0x00005de2 -[SWFMP3 connection:didReceiveData:] (SWFMP3.m:320)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but only because I was looking at a newer version of code than what was compiled into the binary which crashed. When I went back in my source history and found the corresponding version of the source, the line numbers matched exactly.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion which might help – you can use the `dwarfdump` command to inspect the DWARF debugging tables in your `.dSYM` file, and confirm they agree with the output of the symbolicated crash report.

Suppose you see a code address `0x100024914` in your crash report. Note that is not the actual memory address, rather it is the memory address assuming your executable was loaded at a standard memory location of `0x100000000`. For security reasons, the actual memory address is randomised (by adding a random value called the "slide"), but the code addresses in the stack trace of the crash report have the slide removed.

Now you can do:

```
dwarfdump my_program.dsym/Contents/Resources/DWARF/my_program -lookup=0x100024914
```

and you will get as output something like the following:

```
0x0001a9c3: Compile Unit: length = 0x00003367 version = 0x0004 abbr_offset = 0x0000 addr_size = 0x08 (next unit at 0x0001dd2e)

0x0001a9ce: DW_TAG_compile_unit
              DW_AT_producer    ("Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)")
              DW_AT_language    (DW_LANG_C99)
              DW_AT_name        ("./my_program.c")
              DW_AT_stmt_list   (0x0000f323)
              DW_AT_comp_dir    ("/Users/sim/my_program")
              DW_AT_low_pc      (0x0000000100020f70)
              DW_AT_high_pc     (0x0000000100025f58)

0x0001cb5f:   DW_TAG_subprogram
                DW_AT_low_pc    (0x0000000100024070)
                DW_AT_high_pc   (0x0000000100024edb)
                DW_AT_frame_base        (DW_OP_reg6 RBP)
                DW_AT_name      ("my_program_do_some_stuff")
                DW_AT_decl_file ("/Users/sim/my_program/my_program.c")
                DW_AT_decl_line (1165)
                DW_AT_prototyped        (true)
                DW_AT_type      (0x0001b8ae "my_result_t")
                DW_AT_external  (true)

0x0001cbe2:     DW_TAG_lexical_block
                  DW_AT_low_pc  (0x0000000100024117)
                  DW_AT_high_pc (0x0000000100024ec1)
Line info: file 'my_program.c', line 1333, column 22, start line 1165
```

Now, if you confirm that the line number from `dwarfdump` agrees with that from the symbolicated crash report (and I expect it would), that way you know that there is nothing wrong with the crash symbolication engine itself (Apple's undocumented `CoreSymbolication` framework) – it is correctly outputting the DWARF debugging data available to it. If the wrong line number is indeed due to a bug (as opposed to just developer confusion, such as looking at the wrong version of the source file, as mentioned in another answer), it would appear the bug would have to be in the compiler (somewhat unlikely but certainly nothing that hasn't happened before.)